# Can not connect to Raspberry Pi from internet

Tags: router, raspberry-pi, forwarding, ppp

I am trying to use RPi to forward traffic to my home webserver. That is, a remote user should connect to the webserver through internet from anywhere. The setup is as follows: the RPi gets the internet access through the ppp0 interface (cellular internet). The webserver is connected to RPi on eth0 interface:

[image]

I have tried the following [steps](https://github.com/Gagravarr/ogn-pi-internet/blob/master/scripts/forward-eth0-ppp0.sh) to set up forwarding from ppp0 to eth0, but with no success.

I can see from *ifconfig* that the IP address on ppp0 is changed every time I restart the internet connection - I find it reasonable since the cell provider does not reserve static IP address for me. On the other hand, googling "what's my IP" gives me a different IP address. I assume that the later one is my external IP address. Therefore, I use it to ping my RPi, but I do not see any incomming ping traffic in the wireshark. In fact, I tired pinging both IP addresses - obtained via ifconfig and google, but pings timeout.

Since I do not see any incomming ping packages in the wireshark on ppp0 interface, I assume that they do not reach my RPi. But why not? I have a working internet access on ppp0.

Answer (score 1):

Cellular networks don't support incoming TCP connections because they use [carrier grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

> I assume that the later one is my external IP address.

Incorrect assumption. It's the external IP address of the device that's issuing requests for you and probably lots of other people as well. It has no idea that an incoming TCP connection is intended for you.

> Since I do not see any incomming ping packages in the wireshark on ppp0 interface, I assume that they do not reach my RPi. But why not? I have a working internet access on ppp0.

Correct, they don't. They're received by the [middlebox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middlebox) carrier grade NAT device that they were addressed to. This device has a public IP address and bridges the Internet to the carrier's private network. Devices on the private network, such as yours, don't have public IP addresses.

Comment: Thank you, that clears some things out. But then, how should I access RPi from the internet?

Comment: IPV6 or a tunnel of some kind might be an option. But you really need to get internet access that's suitable for running a server if you want to run a server. Why not host the webserver instead?

Comment: It is a small black box - a device - to which I can connect on local network. Wireless internet is the only option. I thought using RPi+fona to provide internet access to the server.

Comment: @nazar Check out https://localtunnel.github.io/www/

Comment: Or the free tier of aws will let you pretty much host whatever you want. https://aws.amazon.com/free/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_US&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=cloud_computing_b_mobile&sc_content=aws_free_p_control_q32016&sc_detail=aws%20free&sc_category=cloud_computing&sc_segment=214926188777&sc_matchtype=p&sc_country=US&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!214926188777!p!!g!!aws%20free&ef_id=WcFGXwAAA6M45QL3:20180622040554:s

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I tried to run "lt" using land ethernet connection and could get the URL, but still could not connect to RPi. When I used cellular inet, the "it -port 80" would give me the URL and then crash complaining about the filerwall, which as far as I know is disabled on RPi.